# How to approach minimizing of the equation

Tags: calculus, optimization

It is known that 3>b>0 and a+b = 3, find the least value of
($3^a + 3^{2b} + 3^{2-b})^3$

How exactly to solve this question? Do I substitute b in the places of a and then find the minimum value of b using calculus? Please help me here.
Thanks

Comment: Try setting $x=3^b$.

Comment: @Blitzer - I got the answer using this, thanks.

Comment: @dxiv - How'd you get this? Seems interesting

Comment: @itsCliffConnor Nevermind, weighted AM-GM was the wrong hint here. Comment removed.

Comment: @dxiv - Ah okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are lots of things with 3 to the power of something, it makes sense to do a substitution with $x = 3^?$. There are plenty of choices for what to put in the place of "?", but since $b$ appears in both of the constraints that suggests it might be a good choice.

Then you have $3^b = x$, so you need to try to replace the other terms with things involving $x$ as well. For example, $3^{2-b} = 3^2 \times 3^{-b} = \frac{9}{x}$.

Once you've written everything in terms of $x$, you'll have an expression you can minimise with a bit of calculus - you might even be able to take a shortcut if you notice something about the relationship of the minima of $f(x)$ and $f(x)^3$.

Just remember to answer the question as asked - finding $x$ is not the end of the solution!

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach, I got the answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share my steps and answer with everyone.

with $x = 3^b$ and a=3-b and let y = $(3^a+3^{2b}+3^{2−b})^3$

$y = (3^{3-b} + 3^{2b} + 3^{2-b})^3$

$y = (\frac{27}{x} + x^2 - \frac{9}{x})^3$

$y = (\frac{18}{x} + x^2)^3$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3(\frac{18}{x} + x^2)^2(-\frac{18}{x^2} + x)$

$0 = 3(\frac{18}{x} + x^2)^2(-\frac{18}{x^2} + 2x)$

$\frac{18}{x^2} = x$

$x^3 = 9$

$y = (\frac{18 + x^3}{x})^3$

$y = \frac{27^3}{9}$

$y = 2187$